# How many buffers are there for text files opened by `open` function in Python?

Tags: python, linux

*This is tested on Linux:*

Passing `buffering` argument to [open](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) doesn't really alter the buffer size:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer.

Here's what I tried, for text files:

```
>>> f = open("/home/user/Desktop/data.txt", "w+", buffering=30)
```

**The anatomy of the `f` object returned by `open`:**

```
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/user/Desktop/data.txt' mode='w+' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> f.buffer
<_io.BufferedRandom name='/home/user/Desktop/data.txt'>
>>> f.buffer.raw
<_io.FileIO name='/home/user/Desktop/data.txt' mode='rb+' closefd=True>
```

`_io.TextIOWrapper` -->  handles encoding, decoding, universal EOF 
translations...

`_io.BufferedRandom` --> read and write buffer.

`io.FileIO` --> This is the file on disk.

If I write to `f.buffer.raw` everything goes straight to the file on disk,  this bypasses the `f.buffer` and the operating system flushs everything straight into the disk file, there's no need to call `os.fsync` with file descriptor to flush the data from Os's buffer to disk.

**The strange thing:**

```
>>> f.write("xyz" * 80)
240
```

I've written by far more than twice the size of the buffer which is specified to be 30 bytes. I expected the buffer to be flushed, and I assumed Python flushed the buffer but Os's buffer still holding data so I called `os.fsync` but nothing was flushed and the file remained empty!

The buffer is not flushed and nothing is written to disk, but writing to the buffer itself where the amount of  the written data exceeded the buffer size, everything gets flushed and data is written to file on disk:

```
>>> f.buffer.write(b"x" * 30)
30
>>> f.buffer.write(b"x")        # now buffer empties itself
1
```

This is strange because  `type(f)` should just encode and add some bells and whistles and then once finished sends bytes to `f.buffer` and when `f.buffer` exceeds 30 as specified to `open`, the buffer should empty itself by flushing. It doesn't seem like that, the problem is `f` relies on its `f._CHUNK_SIZE` when the written data exceed `_CHUNK_SIZE` everything gets written to disk.

- Then `f` acts as a buffer of `str` strings with `_CHUNK_SIZE` set is its size and it flushes its data to `f.buffer`?
- `f.buffer` is the bytes buffer and its value is specified by the buffering`argument of`open`and it flushes its data`f.buffer.raw`?

My initial thinking was that, `type(f)` handles certain tasks like encoding, decoding and then gives its data to the buffer, it's really a wrapper around the buffer. Is it a buffer of `str` strings?

Comment: The documentation says:  *if you’re starting with a buffered Python file object f, first do f.flush(), and then do os.fsync(f.fileno()), to ensure that all internal buffers associated with f are written to disk.*.  Were you doing that?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: @cdarke exactly yes.

Comment: Strange! `f = open("/home/user/Desktop/data.txt", "w+", buffering=30)` behaves as expected in Python 2.7, but not 3.X.

Comment: @cdarke I could actually send the data with `flush`. But when the data exceed the buffer size, Python fails to flush automatically which is not the same for `f.buffer`. You probably misunderstood my question.